# The connection from fetchEventSource does not remain open if I move to another page

Tags: javascript

I am facing a rather strange problem. I'm trying to use the fetchEventSource library (https://github.com/Azure/fetch-event-source) and be able to stream some messages
Everything is fine until, for example, I want to move the page from the browser and return to the previous page to see the message.
If I "leave" the page, that is, I go to another page but I still leave the other page open, the request takes it from the beginning
What I can do?

```
await fetchEventSource(
      `${import.meta.env.VITE_API}${MESSAGE_STREAM_QA_ROUTE(messageId)}`,
      {
        headers: {
          Token: import.meta.env.VITE_TOKEN!,
        },

        onmessage(event: EventSourceMessage) {
          if (event.event !== PING && event.event !== FINISHED_STREAM) {
            console.log(`Message received at ${new Date().toLocaleString()}`, event.data);
            messageCount++;
            answer += parseContent(event.data, messageCount);

            setMessages((prevMessages: IMockStartMessage[]) => {
              const updatedMessages = [...prevMessages];

              if (
                prevMessages.length === 0 ||
                prevMessages[prevMessages.length - 1].type === "question"
              ) {
                updatedMessages.push({ type: "answer", content: answer, bubble: "" });
              } else {
                // Only for streaming
                updatedMessages[updatedMessages.length - 1].content = answer;
                updatedMessages[updatedMessages.length - 1].bubble = "";
              }

              return updatedMessages;
            });
          }
        },

        onclose() {
          setIsStreamActive(false);
          console.log("Request finished: ", new Date().toLocaleString());
        },

        onerror(err: any) {
          console.error(err);
          setIsStreamActive(false);
          console.log("Request finished: ", new Date().toLocaleString());
        },

        signal: abortController.signal,
      }
```